# Smoother shadows in Blender 2.8 (EEVEE)

Tags: mesh, shadows, eevee-render-engine, resolution

So recently I've been really diving into Blender's 2.8 beta, and most importantly EEVEE render engine, and I can't seem to get around these nasty looking shadows. is there a feature I'm missing?[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yea... shadows are a bit complicated to get right with real time graphics. It can get better but not perfect.

You can try if the Soft Shadow option will help your scene. The viewport will be sluggish with it on...

[image]

Comment: As of Blender 2.92, this option is enabled by default